# Failing to get user logged in user object in django

Tags: mysql, django

How can I get logged in user in django. When I tried i get the following error
`'User' object is not iterable`.
My code is as follows

```
def createRoom(request):

    return HttpResponse(request.user)
```

Comment: don't you have a template for this view or are you looking for JsonResponse?

Comment: I want to assign a user a task so I just wanted to get the user object first but seems as request. user. id is accessible

Answer (score 1):

```py
from json import loads

from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core.serializers import serialize

def createRoom(request):
    return JsonResponse(loads(serialize('json', [request.user]))[0])
```